# Will files that are nonexistent be deleted when selecting "All but newest items" in Windows File History?

Tags: windows, backup, file-history

When I select "All but newest items" in Windows File History clean up (https://i.holz.nu/063a2.jpg), will it also delete files which are not present on the original location anymore or does it really only mean it will delete all occurences but the newest and *hold* also these files which are not existent anymore?

Comment: Please translate the image to English

Comment: Done it via a friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've took the risk and tried it by myself. The answer is: **No**, it does not delete nonexistent files.